# Стоит ли делать единую функцию обработки ajax запросов?

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня есть длинный основной файл JS и все множество блоков кода где данные подгружаются через AJAx.

**Стоит ли и есть ли смысл сделать одну единую функцию обработки AJAX запросов?**

Грубо говоря подобная функция:

```
 function loadProgress(metod, url, params, callback) {

   $.ajax({
            type: ''+metod+'',
            url: ""+url+"",
            data: params,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                callback.apply(JSON.parse(data)); 
            }

    });

}
```

Comment: `callback(data);`

Comment: Стоит и есть смысл.

Comment: Не стоит, смысла нет. Лучше по сто раз писать обработку и вывод ошибок AJAX.

Comment: Стоит наконец выкинуть jQuery, выбраться из бункера, и познакомиться с возможностями JS за последние года 4... а также познакомиться с репозиторием npmjs. Использование например axios, автоматически исключает подобные вопросы.

Comment: @yar85 Использование например axios исключает подобные вопросы и порождает новые вопросы :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, но зато эти новые вопросы будут практичными (с какой-то реальной проблемой, вместо сбора мнений) - а значит, с более высоким потенциалом к качеству и полезности. Ну а знакомство с языком, такими его штуками как например промисы, генераторы, и сахар классов - мотивирует по-новому взглянуть на архитектуру, и не городить кучу `$.ajax` в разных участках кода.

Comment: Просто хелпер чисто на аякс - это (имхо) совершенно бесполезный слой... вот хелпер сразу на запрос к апи и гидратацию, уже совсем другое дело.

Comment: @yar85 я понимаю, что нужно вынуть голову из задницы и делать на новых технологиях. Но тут возникает проблема скорости изучения технологий, так как я больше предприниматель, а только потом программист, то мне важна работа ЗДЕСЬ И СЕЙЧАС. Все работает и так. Оно может работать и без этого улучшения, но это моя прихоть. Хотелось бы переписать и сделать единый обработчик AJAX запросов. Когда будет достаточно денег с проекта, тогда всеми "крутыми" штуками займется нормальный кодер, а не я "говнокодер". =) Уж простите.

Comment: Александр, понимаю, но мой совет как раз направлен на то чтобы было легче написать и поддерживать код. Если делать такой хелпер как в вопросе, то хорошо бы сделать его хотя бы просто на промисе. Он сильно упростит жизнь (имею в виду, даже если оставить jQuery), и в получении результата, и в обработке ошибок... А особенно поможет - когда надо делать несколько запросов последовательно. Теорчасть относительно простая: https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-basics